# Google Chart: How to draw the vertical line for bar graph

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to add a vertical line so that there can be a visual distinction for when an element exceeds the value.

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {
    packages: ["corechart"]
    });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ["Element", "Difference", {
                role: "style"
            }],
            ["FOLDERADDUPDATE", 2.29, "#e5e6e2"],
            ["NOTEUPDATE", 3.63, "silver"],
            ["DELETENOTE", 1.12, "e5e4e7"],
            ["NOTEUPDATEANDFOLDER", 5.02, "color: #e5e4e2"],
            ["FOLDERREMOVEUPDATE",.082,"color:e5e5e2"],
            ["PENDINGEVENT", 0,"color:e5e4e4"]
        ]);

        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        view.setColumns([0, 1, {
            calc: "stringify",
            sourceColumn: 1,
            type: "string",
            role: "annotation"
        },
        2]);

        var options = {
            title: "",
            width: 600,
            height: 300,
            bar: {
                groupWidth: "95%"
            },
            legend: {
                position: "none"
            },
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("barchart_values"));
        chart.draw(view, options);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried using Google's ComboChart? I've done it before with combining ColumnChart and LineChart (but this was for horizontal line)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to draw an additional vertical line

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

 
 function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ["Element", "Difference", {
                role: "style"
            }],
            ["FOLDERADDUPDATE", 2.29, "#e5e6e2"],
            ["NOTEUPDATE", 3.63, "silver"],
            ["DELETENOTE", 1.12, "e5e4e7"],
            ["NOTEUPDATEANDFOLDER", 5.02, "color: #e5e4e2"],
            ["FOLDERREMOVEUPDATE",.082,"color:e5e5e2"],
            ["PENDINGEVENT", 0,"color:e5e4e4"]
        ]);

        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        view.setColumns([0, 1, {
            calc: "stringify",
            sourceColumn: 1,
            type: "string",
            role: "annotation"
        },
        2]);

        var options = {
            title: "",
            width: 600,
            height: 300,
            bar: {
                groupWidth: "95%"
            },
            legend: {
                position: "none"
            }
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("barchart_values"));
        chart.draw(view, options);
        drawVAxisLine(chart, 3.0);  //set x value where line shoud be located 
}

function drawVAxisLine(chart,value){
    var layout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var chartArea = layout.getChartAreaBoundingBox();

    var svg = chart.getContainer().getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
    var xLoc = layout.getXLocation(value)
    svg.appendChild(createLine(xLoc,chartArea.top + chartArea.height,xLoc,chartArea.top,'#00cccc',4)); // axis line 
}

function createLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color, w) {
    var line = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
    line.setAttribute('x1', x1);
    line.setAttribute('y1', y1);
    line.setAttribute('x2', x2);
    line.setAttribute('y2', y2);
    line.setAttribute('stroke', color);
    line.setAttribute('stroke-width', w);
    return line;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="barchart_values"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

Insert in options `ticks:` and enter desired values (like 1,3,5,7 in this example)

```
        hAxis: {
            title: 'My Values',
            ticks: [1,3,5,7], 
            minValue: 0
        }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mblenton/97dj9pvm/2/)